# Creating PDF from RPT file in Classic ASP

Tags: crystal-reports, asp-classic

I have a windows 2008 application server that hosts a web application built in classic asp. i have a crystal report server which is a windows 2008 server. both are on the same network.

I want to create pdf file from rpt file in the application server. Is there a way to do this without installing crystal reports on the application server?

-Vivek

Answer (score 0):

This requires a bit more thinking but in theory you could do something like this:

- Classic ASP is not able to work with Crystal Reports (as far as I know)
- However, your IIS7 is able to handle both ASP.NET and Classic ASP
- You could develop a service in .NET that does the conversion for you
- This could work on your application server utilizinig the Crystal redistributable runtime libraries

Like I said this is just a theory. Give it some thought and if you run into any trouble let me know...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know nothing about Crystal Reports Server, but surely there a way to tell the server to process a file and generate a PDF. You can then pick up the file from the other server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use crystal reports from classic asp but you have to use the crystal reports dlls on your application server (where asp is executed)

`dim oApp : set oApp = Server.CreateObject("CrystalRuntime.Application.10")`

and so on...